# How long does it take eclipselink to flush its shared cache

Tags: java, eclipselink

**Does anyone know the exact time eclipselink need to flush its shared cache ?** I have made changes directly to the database. As the application written in java uses eclipselink for persistence the changes made directly to the database are reflected only after a certain duration of time. This is because of eclipselink's shared cache as it caches the value.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your configuration. From the EclipseLink [user guide](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Caching/Expiration):

> **By default**, entities remain in the shared cache until they are
>   explicitly deleted or garbage collected.

This also further depends on your [Cache Type & Size](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Caching/Type_and_Size) configuration.

The first link states how to set an expiration time on particular entities by using the `expiry` or `expiryTimeOfDay` attributes of the `@Cache` annotation, e.g. `@Cache(expiry = 600000)`. I don't think there is a global setting that can be applied to all entities, but this might help: [Configuring Cache Expiration at the Project Level](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Configuring_a_Project_%28ELUG%29#Configuring_Cache_Expiration_at_the_Project_Level)

Alternatively, if you're expecting data to be stale, you can [explicitly refresh the cache](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Caching#How_to_refresh_the_cache).